# two way binding not working even with dot notation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm starting with AngularJS and I am using a controller variable to navigate an array of questions, and it is working when using nextQuestion function, index gets updated and the next question is shown in the view, but if I try to obtain the same value (index) in a different function, it always returns 0.

I have seen on other questions that you should use an object to contain the variable to not manipulate primitive types directly in the controller, but it still does not work.

My controller:

```
myApp.controller('SurveyController',['$scope','$http', '$location','$routeParams','surveyMetrics','DataService',function($scope,$http, $location,$routeParams,surveyMetrics,DataService){
    console.log('LOADED QUIZ CONTROLLER');
      var vm = this;
      vm.scope = {
        index: 0
      };
      vm.surveyMetrics = surveyMetrics;
      vm.surveyQuestions = DataService.surveyQuestions;
      vm.DataService = DataService;

      /*
      vm.getQuestions = function(){
          $http.get('/api/questions').then(function(response){
          $scope.questions = response.data;
        });  
      }
      */

      /*
      vm.activateSurvey = function(){
        surveyMetrics.changeState(true);
      }
      */
     vm.getCurrentIndex = function(){
       return vm.scope.index;
     }

      vm.nextQuestion = function () {
        console.log('NEXT QUESTION!');
        console.log('NUMBER OF QUESTIONS: '+ vm.surveyQuestions.length);
        var currentIndex = vm.getCurrentIndex();
        var newIndex = currentIndex+1;
        scope = {};

        if (currentIndex == vm.surveyQuestions.length) {
          newIndex = vm.surveyQuestions.length -1;
        }

        vm.scope.index = newIndex;
        console.log('Inside Object: '+vm.scope)
        console.log('vm.index'+vm.scope.index); 
        console.log('vm.indexFunction'+vm.getCurrentIndex());
      }

      /*
      vm.previousQuestion = function () {
        console.log('PREVIOUS QUESTION!');
        console.log('NUMBER OF QUESTIONS: '+ vm.surveyQuestions.length);

        if (vm.scope.index == 0) {
          vm.scope.index = 0;
        }else{
          vm.scope.index--;
        }

      }
      */
      vm.activeSurveyQuestion = function(questionId,index){
        console.log('question id and index',questionId,index);
        if (questionId == index) {
          var navBtn = document.getElementById('navBtn_'+index);
          navBtn.classList.add('active');
        }
      }


      vm.navigateSurvey = function () {

          var answerPane = document.getElementById('answer-pane');

          document.onkeydown = function (e) {
            console.log('INSIDE KEYDOWN: ')
            e.preventDefault();

            var pressedKey = e.keyCode;
            console.log('PRESSED KEY IN SURVEY: ' + pressedKey);

            if (pressedKey === rightArrow) {
              console.log('survey - right arrow pressed');
              document.getElementById('nextQuestionBtn').click();

              console.log('FUCKING INDEX FML!: '+vm.getCurrentIndex()+' | '+vm.scope.index);
              var questionType = DataService.getQuestionType(vm.scope.index);
              console.log('Survey Controller: question type:  '+questionType);
            }
            if (pressedKey === leftArrow) {
              console.log('survey - left arrow pressed');
              document.getElementById('previousQuestionBtn').click();


            }
(...)
```

```
My View:
 <!--Satisfaction Survey-->
    <div ng-controller="SurveyController as survey" ng-init="survey.getSurvey();">
      <!-- 
        <p ng-repeat="question in survey.surveyQuestions" ng-show ="survey.surveyMetrics.surveyActive">
          {{question.question}}
        </p>
      -->
        <!--Survey Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="surveyModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="text-center"> Customer Satisfaction Survey</div>
            <div class="modal-header">

              <h4 class="modal-title">{{survey.surveyQuestions[survey.getCurrentIndex()].question}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body survey" id="answer-pane">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 survey-left-arrow" ng-click="survey.previousQuestion();" id="previousQuestionBtn">
                     <p>&#8249;</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <!-- <p ng-repeat="answer in survey.surveyQuestions[survey.index].answers">{{answer}}</p> --> 
                      <p ng-repeat="answer in survey.surveyQuestions[survey.getCurrentIndex()].answers">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="answerId_{{survey.getCurrentIndex()}}"
                                ng-class="{'survey-check-box': (survey.surveyQuestions[survey.getCurrentIndex()].type !== 'SingleChoice'),
                                           'survey-btn_{{($index+1)}}': (survey.surveyQuestions[survey.getCurrentIndex()].type === 'SingleChoice')}">
                          <input type="checkbox" ng-if="survey.surveyQuestions[survey.getCurrentIndex()].type !== 'SingleChoice'"> {{answer}}
                        </button>
                      </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2 survey-right-arrow " ng-click="survey.nextQuestion();" id="nextQuestionBtn">
                      <p>&#8250;</p>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              <strong> <p>Question: {{survey.surveyQuestions[survey.scope.index].questionNum}} of {{survey.surveyQuestions.length}}</p> </strong> 
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
           <!-- <nav aria-label="Survey navigation">
              <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
                <div ng-repeat="question in survey.surveyQuestions" >
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" id = "navBtn_$index" ng-click="survey.index = $index">{{question.id}}</a>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </nav> -->
          </div>

        </div>
```

I would like for the controller to change the variable and the view to update accordingly

Thank you for your time and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'survey.scope.index' not 'survey.index' in your HTML. I think you may be unclear the difference between using 'this' and '$scope'. You're mixing the two together which is not necessary. I would suggest removing 'scope' and just reference it in your HTML as 'survey.index'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just named the object scope,as it could be 'pickles', I don't think I am confused in that regard
I ended up moving all data manipulation into a factory,and the problem is solved.
Anyway, thank you very much for your time.
have a good one